# DevicePolicyManager `lockNow();` Not working After device reboot

Tags: android, device-policy-manager

So i have a `BroadcastReceiver` which is registered as :

```
<receiver
        android:name="package.MyBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And i am using `DevicePolicyManager` to lock the device as soon as User Unlocks the device - as `MyBroadcastReceiver` receives a broadcast see code below:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {


    deviceManger = (DevicePolicyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(startMain);

                    deviceManger = (DevicePolicyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
                    //also tried with context..getApplicationContext() but no luck
                    deviceManger.lockNow();
                }
            }
        };

}
```

So this code works fine but when the device is powered off and restarted then :

```
deviceManger = (DevicePolicyManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
                    deviceManger.lockNow();
```

the above coed seems to have no affect on the device i.e the device won't lock but this was working fine just before the device restart.
I tried adding logs and i am sure the code gets executed but `locknow()` seems to have no affect on device ...

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I found out it won't work for the first one or two times but starts working after that ...